# Display sub category of specific category link hovered in navigation menu toggle drop down sub menu in php

Tags: php, sql

I want to display only the sub category that is belongs to a specific category clicked from the navigation menu.But this code dispalys all the sub categories on hover

**PHP code :**

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "carz");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    //echo $row["cname"];
    //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["cid"], $row["cname"]);
    echo "<ul class='dropdown'>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo '<li ><a href="#" class="dropbtn">' . $row["cname"] .'</a>';
         echo '<ul class="dropdown-content">';
          $query2 = "SELECT * FROM categories_sub WHERE cid=".$row["cid"]."";
          $result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
         // loop through the sub cats
         while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
             // if there were sub sub cats etc you just keep this code going deeper
             echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row2["csname"].'</a></li>';
         } // end sub cats loop
         echo '</ul>';
      // end check for results
     echo "</li>";  
    }

/* free result set */
echo "</ul>";
$result->free();
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: There is no issue with your code. Please check the html after the query is executed to see if the html elements for sub category is created correctly

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand right your question, but yes - this code displays subcategories for all categories. The simplest way to get only one sub category to modify out query with WHERE cid=<parameter ID given by clicked category>. But at all the right way is to use only internal query and remove the external one.